# Cant connect to Database in a docker container with Table plus using vscode devcontainer

Tags: database, docker, vscode-devcontainer, table-plus

Hello i need some help im using TablePlus to connect to my database but this isn't working with adding the forwardPorts
devcontainer.json

```
    {
        "name": "Node.js & PostgreSQL",
        "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
        "service": "app",
        "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
          "forwardPorts": [5432]
    }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ../..:/workspaces:cached
        # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
        command: sleep infinity
        # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
        network_mode: service:db
        # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally.
        # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        # Add "forwardPorts": ["5432"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward PostgreSQL locally.
        # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)
volumes:
    postgres-data:
```

Dockerfile

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-18`

I already add forwardPorts in devcontainer.json and port in docker-compose.yml
this doesn't change something

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/) for `devcontainer.json`, you have to specify the container name together with the port, when using docker compose and you want to forward a port from a container which is not the primary container.

The line in your `devcontainer.json` should be:

```
"forwardPorts": ["db:5432"]
```